# Select column based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I would like to select a different column based on a value billback_id.  If billback_id = 3 then I want to select bhh.ctv otherwise I want bsih.total. Is this possible in a join?

```
select
bsih.invoice_amount, 
case when bhh.billback_id = 3 then bhh.ctv else bsih.total end as bsih.total
from [movement].[dbo].[billback_header_history] as bhh
left join
(select invoice_number, invoice_extension,store_number, sum(ctv) as total
from [movement].[dbo].[bsih]
where ctv <> 0
group by invoice_number, invoice_extension, store_number
) as bsih
on bhh.invoice_number = bsih.invoice_number
where last_movement_update between '2022/01/08' and '2022/01/14'
```

error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 111 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'if'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 111 Incorrect syntax near the
> keyword 'then'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 119 Incorrect syntax
> near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: @DaleK Could you put that in an answer with case?  I tried case got error as well.

Comment: I edit with the case I tried

Comment: This is the error `as bsih.total` you can't alias with a dot unless you escape it e.g. `as [bsih.total]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you can use case (instead of if) in the select.

The statement is:

`case when {condition1} then {result1} when {condition2} then {result2} else {result3} end`.

So, we could have:

```
select
    bsih.invoice_amount, 
    case when bhh.billback_id = 3 then bhh.ctv
        else bhih.total end as col2
from [movement].[dbo].[billback_header_history] as bhh
left join (
    select invoice_number, invoice_extension,store_number, sum(ctv) as total
    from [movement].[dbo].[bsih]
    where ctv <> 0
    group by invoice_number, invoice_extension, store_number
) as bsih on bhh.invoice_number = bsih.invoice_number
where last_movement_update between '2022/01/08' and '2022/01/14'
```

Comment: OP has already tried that...

Comment: You might want to point out, that the error you actually fixed was the new column alias.